# Misplaced \omit in a table

Tags: tables

I am not sure how to fix this error. It is from an [already accepted paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPRW_2019/papers/WiCV/Jalal_SIDOD_A_Synthetic_Image_Dataset_for_3D_Object_Pose_Recognition_CVPRW_2019_paper.pdf) that I am trying to submit to arXiv.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand\xmark{x}
\newcommand\cmark{y}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\rb}[1]{\makebox[20pt]{\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}%
\begin{table*}[ht]
    % \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrc|ccccccccc}
    Dataset & \#objects  &  \#frames & Description & 
    % \rb{depth} & \rb{stereo} & \rb{\multicolumn{1}{c{0.5cm}}{\centering 3D \\ pose}}  &
    \makebox[10px]{\rb{depth}} & \makebox[10px]{\rb{stereo}} & 
    \makebox[9px]{\rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.7cm}}{\centering 3D \\ pose}}}  &
   \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{1.1cm}}{\centering full \\ rotation}}  & \rb{occlusion} & 
   \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{1.2cm}}{\centering extreme \\ lighting}}  & 
    \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{1.2cm}}{\centering segmen \\ tation}}  & 
    \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.9cm}}{\centering bbox \\ coords}} & 
    \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering flying \\ distractors}} \\
    \hline

    UW RGB~\cite{lai2011large} & 300 & 250k & various & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    LINEMOD~\cite{hinterstoisser2012model} & 15 & 18k & various & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    Pascal3D+~\cite{xiang2014beyond} & 12 & 30k & various & 
    \xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

   % Brachman et al.~\cite{brachmann2014learning} & 20 & 10k & various & 
  %  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    Rutgers APC~\cite{rennie2016dataset} & 24 & 10k & warehouse & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    T-LESS~\cite{hodan2017t} & 30 & 10k & industrial & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    YCB Video~\cite{xiang2017posecnn} & 21 & 134k & household & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

    Falling Things~\cite{tremblay2018falling} & 21 & 60k & household & 
    \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

    SIDOD & 21 & 144k & household & 
    \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Object pose and detection datasets with at least 10,000 frames.} %TODO: finish caption.}
    \label{tab:comparison}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Error shown in overleaf pro is:
[image]

[image]

Here is the entire latex for the 3-page article https://pastebin.com/wLaT1rH9

Comment: `\multicolumn` needs to be the first thing in its cell so probably `\rb` is not allowed but we can't say as you have given no indication of the definitions you are using. Please supply an example that produces the error.

Comment: @David I can add you as an editor in the overleaf if you could share your email with jalal@bu.edu thanks

Comment: no sorry that's not how the site works, please edit the question so that the example demonstrates the problem. But whatever the definition of `\rb`  it is unlikely to be allowed before `\multicolumn`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here is the entire latex for the 3 page article. Does it work? https://pastebin.com/wLaT1rH9

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Please also include the definition of `\rb`(something like `\newcommand{\rb}{.....}` that is in your preamble).

Comment: No this question is archived _forever_ and will make no sense if the overleaf of pastebin links change. It really is not hard for you to make a small one page example that just had that table and the minimum required definitions so it works.

Comment: I did look at your pastebin but even that version is not usable it uses a cvpr package that is not supplied and it doesn't define `\rb` so we can't test the table. (note no document written this century should be using the epsfig package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `\rb`is defined in the document. Although not in the preamble where one would expect the definition. Instead you can find the corresponding `\newcommand` in line 130 right before the table.

Comment: I made your example usable this time.

Comment: @leandriis thanks I put a MWE above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\multicolumn` needs to be the first thing in its cell. but you do not need need multicolumn here, I think you can just use parbox rather than `\multicolumn{1}{p}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand\xmark{x}
\newcommand\cmark{y}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\rb}[1]{\makebox[20pt]{\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}%
\begin{table*}[ht]
    % \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrc|ccccccccc}
    Dataset & \#objects  &  \#frames & Description & 
    % \rb{depth} & \rb{stereo} & \rb{\parbox{0.5cm}{\centering 3D \\ pose}}  &
    \makebox[10px]{\rb{depth}} & \makebox[10px]{\rb{stereo}} & 
    \makebox[9px]{\rb{\parbox{0.7cm}{\centering 3D \\ pose}}}  &
   \rb{\parbox{1.1cm}{\centering full \\ rotation}}  & \rb{occlusion} & 
   \rb{\parbox{1.2cm}{\centering extreme \\ lighting}}  & 
    \rb{\parbox{1.2cm}{\centering segmen \\ tation}}  & 
    \rb{\parbox{0.9cm}{\centering bbox \\ coords}} & 
    \rb{\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering flying \\ distractors}} \\
    \hline

    UW RGB~\cite{lai2011large} & 300 & 250k & various & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    LINEMOD~\cite{hinterstoisser2012model} & 15 & 18k & various & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    Pascal3D+~\cite{xiang2014beyond} & 12 & 30k & various & 
    \xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

   % Brachman et al.~\cite{brachmann2014learning} & 20 & 10k & various & 
  %  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    Rutgers APC~\cite{rennie2016dataset} & 24 & 10k & warehouse & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    T-LESS~\cite{hodan2017t} & 30 & 10k & industrial & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    YCB Video~\cite{xiang2017posecnn} & 21 & 134k & household & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

    Falling Things~\cite{tremblay2018falling} & 21 & 60k & household & 
    \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

    SIDOD & 21 & 144k & household & 
    \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Object pose and detection datasets with at least 10,000 frames.} %TODO: finish caption.}
    \label{tab:comparison}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: added `% for checkmarks and x marks
\usepackage{xcolor}

% for checkmarks and x marks
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{34, 139, 34}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{{\color{cgreen}\ding{51}}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{{\color{red}\ding{55}}}%

\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{34, 139, 34}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont` so that it shows the checkmarks same as the original article

Comment: @Mona would be better to remove them from the question. examples should only use packages related to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Rotated headers are awkward to place, particularly if long and needing to be split into two lines.

I suggest abbreviation and a legend at the bottom of the table.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\xmark{x}
\newcommand\cmark{y}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccc @{\hspace{0.5em}} *{9}{c} }
\toprule
  Dataset & \#objects  &  \#frames & Description &
  (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) \\
\midrule
  UW RGB~\cite{lai2011large} & 300 & 250k & various & 
  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

  LINEMOD~\cite{hinterstoisser2012model} & 15 & 18k & various & 
  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

  Pascal3D+~\cite{xiang2014beyond} & 12 & 30k & various & 
  \xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

 % Brachman et al.~\cite{brachmann2014learning} & 20 & 10k & various & 
 % \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

  Rutgers APC~\cite{rennie2016dataset} & 24 & 10k & warehouse & 
  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

  T-LESS~\cite{hodan2017t} & 30 & 10k & industrial & 
  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

  YCB Video~\cite{xiang2017posecnn} & 21 & 134k & household & 
  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

  Falling Things~\cite{tremblay2018falling} & 21 & 60k & household & 
  \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

  SIDOD & 21 & 144k & household & 
  \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedright
  (1):~depth; (2):~stereo; (3):~3D~pose; (4):~full~rotation; (5):~occlusion;
  (6):~extreme~lighting; (7):~segmentation; (8):~bbox~coords; (9):~flying~distractors}}}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Object pose and detection datasets with at least 10,000 frames.} %TODO: finish caption.}
    \label{tab:comparison}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer renders differently from what is in the original published article table 1. https://pasteboard.co/JcmSQXi.png